# Python coding to convert US dollars into Japanese Yen failed

Tags: python, python-3.x

The below code doesn't work. The main purpose of the below code is to convert US dollars into Japanese yen. Info of receipt is written in Jun7.csv, and I want to put the calculated result into Jun7.txt. Hope my explanation makes sense. Thanks for your help in advance.

```
with open('Jun7.csv', encoding='utf-8') as f:
    for row in f:
        columns = row.rstrip().split(',')
        name = columns[0]
        price = float(columns[1])

        multi = price * 110

with open('Jun7.txt', 'a', encoding='utf-8') as wf:
        wf.write(name + ', ' + str(multi))
```

---

for the record, below is the contents of Jun7.csv

```
WHITE WAVE SLK SY VA W, 3.85
GG STMR MX VEG x 2, 3.98
STFFER BKD CHKN, 3.39
TINY TWIST PRETZ, 3.29
ROTISSERE CHICKEN, 6.99
BANANAS, 1.48
KENTWOOD DISTLD WTR, 1.48
```

Comment: What exactly is the problem? Are you getting an error? The wrong results?

Comment: Right: As written, we don't actually know the problem you're experiencing. Does it not write anything out? Are the results not calculated correctly? Is it an issue while reading? Please edit your question to be more specific. Otherwise, there's really no way to help, aside from just guessing.

Answer (score 3):

You are not saving `name` and `multi` in a separate variable, so you end up only writing the last value that has been seen.

Consider modifying your code as follows:

```
yen_prices = []
with open('Jun7.csv') as dollar_file:
    for dollar_entry in dollar_file:
        columns = dollar_entry.rstrip().split(',')
        name = columns[0]
        dollar_price = float(columns[1])

        yen_entry = name, dollar_price * 110
        yen_prices.append(yen_entry)

with open('Jun7.txt', 'w') as yen_file:
    for yen_entry in yen_prices:
        yen_file.write("{}, {}\n".format(yen_entry[0], yen_entry[1]))
```

Comment: While correct, is not the best way to do it. ( + 1 though )

Comment: Indeed, this is not the best way to achieve such a conversion task. However, I was not aiming at giving the best solution, and preferred to give the author an answer that does not diverge too much from his initial attempt (+1 too!).

Comment: Thank you for your answer! It worked pretty well. Again, thank you so much!!

Answer (score 2):

You calculate the price in yen for every line in your input file, but you write only one line (i.e. with the last calculated value).
You can do everything in the same `for` loop

```
with open('Jun7.csv', encoding='utf-8') as f:
    with open('Jun7.txt', 'a', encoding='utf-8') as wf:
        for row in f:
            columns = row.rstrip().split(',')
            name = columns[0]
            price = float(columns[1])

            multi = price * 110
            wf.write(name + ', ' + str(multi))
```

Answer (score 2):

The problem is your order of operations. As is, your code calculates the `name`, `price` and `multi` of the first row, and then overwrites all those values with the second row, and then overwrites them with the third row... etc until it has reached the final row.

***Then*** it wries `name, multi` to `Jun7.txt`, i.e. it only writes the values taken from the last line of `Jun7.csv`.

You need to either store the information from each line some way, so it can all be written at the end, or, by just rearranging a couple of lines, you can write as you scan each line:

```
with open('Jun7.csv', encoding='utf-8') as f:
    with open('Jun7.txt', 'a', encoding='utf-8') as wf: #Open both files at same time
        for row in f:
            columns = row.rstrip().split(',')
            name = columns[0]
            price = float(columns[1]) 
            multi = price * 110

            wf.write(name + ', ' + str(multi)) #Write info at end of for loop
                                               #before overwriting variables
                                               #in next iteration
```